# Why does linux dump clean MAP_ANONYMOUS memory pages to core dump?

Tags: c++, linux

I would like to use mmap to map LARGE contiguous memory regions into my process.  This is just a large pre-allocated buffer, most of which is unlikely to every be used.  I can actually create Terabytes of such memory regions even though that exceeds my physical memory + hard disk size.  Linux will map in pages as I access addresses in my mapped region.  Unfortunately, if I generate a core dump after calling mmap, but before touching the new memory region, the core dump will include that LARGE memory region.  Why?  Linux would have to page in a new page of zero bulked filled memory just to write it out to the core file.

Why would I want to do this?  My code would be simpler and more efficient if my producer could always append data to a single contiguous buffer and my consumer could read the data behind the producer and assume that all data between its read head and the producer's write head is consumable.  I planned to use madvise after my read head advanced pass a page boundary to let the OS know that it need not save those pages of memory for me anymore.

Comment: Did you consider using  `MAP_NORESERVE` for the first large map?

Comment: MAP_NORESERVE helps relax the heuristic checks allowing mmap to succeed where it might not have.  Unfortunately it doesn't prevent the core dump from including unmodified zero filled pages in the core dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the core dump will include that LARGE memory region. Why?

Because the kernel is not optimized to reduce core file size under these conditions.

It's likely that the kernel *can* look at every page in a given memory region, and skip all pages that are not modified. I am not sure such a patch would be accepted though.

You could use google [user-level coredumper](http://code.google.com/p/google-coredumper/) instead. It does trim trailing zero-filled pages.